# Is there a way to download the merge request details and save it to a xml file?

Tags: python, api, gitlab, merge-request

I have a GitLab repo. I want to download all the details of the merge requests I have done in my remote repo and save it to a file which can be xml or txt or csv or anything..

Is there anyway to do this?

I am behind this for a long time and still I don't get any ways to do this.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to get all merge request details as a file.

However, you can use the [Gitlab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#get-single-mr) to get all details for a specific merge request. You can then of course collect all available details and create a summary file for those.